# SONAR code violation filtering by user

Tags: plugins, filter, sonarqube

Does anyone know if there is SONAR extension for filtering violations by user/author who introduced them ?

Idea is to pick a user, and SONAR would list all violations made in the code by that specific user.

Maybe some ideas could be provided if it is possible to achieve such functionality ?

Thanks.

Comment: sonar has a source code management plugin: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin. But this just marks who last changed a line in the view.

Comment: Agreed. You can use Sonar's code review functionality to assign violations to users. Presumably one would need a plugin which extends this functionality to auto-assign these violations based on the last user to touch the particular file/package

Comment: Why not raise a JIRA request to the Sonar developers?

Comment: Thanks you for fast and helpful replies.

Comment: this is something we are working on, and you should have some first functionalities in Sonar 2.14. So stay tuned! ;-)

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam Hi Fabrice i saw the comment and it seemed interesting. I am using Sonar 3.5.1, do you know if the functionality you mentioned exists in that version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use the REST-API to get the violations (something like 'http://sonar-host/api/violations?resource=1&depth=-1&priorities=BLOCKER,CRITICAL,MAJOR') to get the interesting violations and then use 'svn annotate' to get the relevant annotions and therefore the user. That is what I did, and in the meantime it works well.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube, "Issues" Main manu/tab provides this feature. You can do all sorts of filtering by project, by user etc through that feature.
[image: SonarQube Issues feature]

This is in version 4.3.2